Confusing behaviour of scipy.stats.ttest_ind
I'm using (or trying to use scipy.stats.ttest_ind) like this:
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind, norm

def test_ttest_ind():
    rng = np.random.default_rng(43)

    rvs1 = stats.norm.rvs(loc=15, scale=10, size=500, random_state=rng)
    rvs2 = stats.norm.rvs(loc=15, scale=10, size=500, random_state=rng)

    print("Same same")
    print(ttest_ind(rvs1, rvs2))
    print(ttest_ind(rvs1, rvs2, equal_var=False))
    print()

    print("Same size diff variance")
    rvs3 = stats.norm.rvs(loc=15, scale=20, size=500, random_state=rng)
    print(ttest_ind(rvs1, rvs3))
    print(ttest_ind(rvs1, rvs3, equal_var=False))
equal_var=False))
    print()

    print("Diff size diff variance")
    rvs4 = stats.norm.rvs(loc=15, scale=20, size=100, random_state=rng)
    print(ttest_ind(rvs1, rvs4))
    print(ttest_ind(rvs1, rvs4, equal_var=False))
equal_var=False))
    print()


But the results are confusing to me...
Same same
TtestResult(statistic=np.float64(0.7788368), pvalue=np.float64(0.43626), df=np.float64(998.0))
TtestResult(statistic=np.float64(0.7788368), pvalue=np.float64(0.43626), df=np.float64(997.167))

# OK all the above looks good.


Same size diff variance
TtestResult(statistic=np.float64(0.5116953), pvalue=np.float64(0.60897), df=np.float64(998.0))
TtestResult(statistic=np.float64(0.5116953), pvalue=np.float64(0.60901), df=np.float64(730.112))

# The variance *is* different... So how come pooling it or not has no effect?


Diff size diff variance
TtestResult(statistic=np.float64(-5.125124), pvalue=np.float64(4.0e-07), df=np.float64(598.0))
TtestResult(statistic=np.float64(-3.577155), pvalue=np.float64(0.00051), df=np.float64(111.951))

# Now the sample size differs, pooling the variance seems to have a huge effect! Why?


Sorry if this is a very stupid question, I'm getting stuck with 'more advanced stuff', so looking to understand the basics before I know I'm confused about more complicated stuffs.

Can we simplify the question by removing the permutation t-test from consideration? It seems like the same question can be asked about the asymptotic tests (no permutation argument).
Also, have you looked at how the statistics are calculated? The statistics themselves reduce to the same thing when the sample sizes are equal, whether you're doing Welch's t-test (equal_var=False) or not. The null distributions of the two must not be too different in this case, either, given that the two p-values are similar. Is the question about SciPy or the test itself?

Right, good point

Now that I look at my code, I think the 'huge effect' I was worried about is just a coincidence of how I'm generating a totally new distribution in each test.
If I just 'extend' the first distribution to change the size, I'm seeing results that look more 'expected'...
def test_ttest_ind2():

    rng = np.random.default_rng()

    rvs1 = norm.rvs(loc=15, scale=10, size=100, random_state=rng)
    rvs2 = norm.rvs(loc=35, scale=80, size=200, random_state=rng)

    print("Same size same variance")
    print_ttest_ind(ttest_ind(rvs1, rvs2[:100]))
    print_ttest_ind(ttest_ind(rvs1, rvs2[:100], equal_var=False))
    print()

    print("Diff size (  1) diff variance")
    print_ttest_ind(ttest_ind(rvs1, rvs2[:101]))
    print_ttest_ind(ttest_ind(rvs1, rvs2[:101], equal_var=False))
    print()

    print("Diff size ( 50) diff variance")
    print_ttest_ind(ttest_ind(rvs1, rvs2[:150]))
    print_ttest_ind(ttest_ind(rvs1, rvs2[:150], equal_var=False))
    print()

    print("Diff size (100) diff variance")
    print_ttest_ind(ttest_ind(rvs1, rvs2[:200]))
    print_ttest_ind(ttest_ind(rvs1, rvs2[:200], equal_var=False))
    print()


for _ in range(10):
    test_ttest_ind2()
    print()

Which spits out things like this:

t-stat:  -2.052          p-value: 0.04144        df: 198.0
t-stat:  -2.052          p-value: 0.04269        df: 101.7

Diff size (  1) diff variance
t-stat:  -2.079          p-value: 0.03887        df: 199.0
t-stat:  -2.089          p-value: 0.03914        df: 102.8

Diff size ( 50) diff variance
t-stat:  -1.792          p-value: 0.07437        df: 248.0
t-stat:  -2.184          p-value: 0.03050        df: 155.2

Diff size (100) diff variance
t-stat:  -2.211          p-value: 0.02782        df: 298.0
t-stat:  -3.095          p-value: 0.00224        df: 210.7


Same size same variance
t-stat:  -2.299          p-value: 0.02255        df: 198.0
t-stat:  -2.299          p-value: 0.02354        df: 102.1

Diff size (  1) diff variance
t-stat:  -2.406          p-value: 0.01703        df: 199.0
t-stat:  -2.418          p-value: 0.01736        df: 103.1

Diff size ( 50) diff variance
t-stat:  -3.437          p-value: 0.00069        df: 248.0
t-stat:  -4.187          p-value: 0.00005        df: 155.5

Diff size (100) diff variance
t-stat:  -3.123          p-value: 0.00197        df: 298.0
t-stat:  -4.374          p-value: 0.00002        df: 210.0

So basically, NOT pooling the variance (which is correct given these inputs) tends to give slightly lower p-values, with the p-value (and the difference in p-values) being a function of the size of the second sample, which is entirely expected (more data gives more evidence against the null hypothesis).
I think I was perhaps confused by what the test is doing (finding a difference in the mean), the test ISN'T looking for a difference in the variance, although the latter is important in how the test (for the difference in the means) is formulated.
So I think I'm not confused any more ;-)
